# How do I get Jersey 2.2 (JAX-RS) to generate log output, including Json request bodies

Tags: jersey, jetty

I'm running a Jersey 2.2 Servlet inside Jetty 9.0.4 in order to serve REST requests.

Mostly everything is good and requests get served, but I have never seen **ANY** log from Jersey classes. And I can't find any doco indicating what chickens I need to sacrifice to make that happen with Jersey 2.2

So my first question is - what do I need to do to get Jersey to generate some log.

When a request does run awry (eg because the Json request body can't be parsed) Jersey will throw a ContainerException with message like "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token" etc. At that point it would be **really** lovely to have logged the incoming request body so I can inspect the Json. Again I can't find anything in the current doco outlining such a beast although I'm sure there is one. And in any case until I solve question 1 up above it's moot.

So my 2nd question is how do I log the incoming request body (without disrupting the request).

The Jersey Servlet config in web.xml looks like:

```
<servlet >
    <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>au.com.xandar.wirelesstiming.recorder.web.rest.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My JerseyApplication is:

```
public final class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        super(
            //JacksonFeature.class   // Switching on Jackson
            // (My) JerseyLoggingFilter.class       // Log requests using Jersey ContainerRequestFilter 
            MyApplicationEventListener.class        // Log Requests using Jersey RequestEventListener
        );
        packages("au.com.xandar.wirelesstiming.recorder");

        // Enable LoggingFilter & output entity.
        // NB This does NOT generate any log.
        registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(JerseyApplication.class.getName()), true));
    }
}
```

Comment: What *Jersey classes* logs would you expect/appreciate?

Comment: I'm really only interested in the Request/Response. But having log that indicated that the Servlet has started and was serving would have at least assured the logging was working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jersey doesn't log much by itself. For 2.x we're working on a *development mode* which would include tracing support (see [Tracing in Jersey](https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/tracing_in_jersey)), default logging of incoming requests / outgoing responses (incl. entity bodies and tracing messages). This feature should be out soon.

Regarding your second question - you can register [LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html) which is able to log incoming requests / outgoing responses (method, headers, ..) as well as entity bodies (when configured). You can configure it via (3rd option illustrates how to turn-on entity logging):

`web.xml` (add it to the JAX-RS servlet definition):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

`Application` extension:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>() {{
            // Add your resources.
            add(HelloWorldResource.class);

            // Add LoggingFilter.
            add(LoggingFilter.class);
        }};
    }
}
```

`ResourceConfig` instance (demonstrating also outputting the entity here):

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        // Resources - add your package name here to enable package scanning.
        packages(...);

        // Enable LoggingFilter & output entity.     
        registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(MyApplication.class.getName()), true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Michal, I tried adding the web.xml version but I still no logging of the Requests. I've updated my question to include the web.xml snippet

Comment: I'm not getting any log for option 3 either.

Comment: You should see some logs done by Jersey (at `INFO` level) in `<jetty_home>/logs/*.stderrout.log`, at least something like `Aug 16, 2013 12:15:24 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.3-SNAPSHOT 2013-08-14 18:36:24...` Isn't this the case?

Comment: I'm running Jetty via the maven-jetty-plugin, so no jetty_home. Jetty log normally just goes to System.out. I'm not seeing any log about Jersey app initialisation or any other Jersey log (except below). But now that I have the JerseyLogger configured in both web.xml and in MyApplication I'm getting: `Aug 16, 2013 8:28:41 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Cannot new create registration for component type class org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter: Existing previous registration found for the type.`

Comment: Since you want to see request entity bodies remove the `web.xml` init-parram adding the logging filter and leave only the `Application` one. Can you see other `INFO` logs (i.e. initialization of Jetty server: `2013-08-16 12:49:28.983:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.4.v20130625`)?

Comment: OK, removed the web.xml config, LoggingFilter only configured in (My)JerseyApplication. Now there is no Jersey log at all. But i see all of my log and all Jetty log like `12013-08-16 21:16:34.830:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.4.v20130625`
`

Comment: Can you show us your `JerseyApplication`? Do you use some other logging mechanisms in your app?

Comment: JerseyApplication added to question. I log using the Jetty logger API configured to write to Std err. I have switched on DEBUG for my classes and Jersey and INFO for Jetty.

Comment: I feel really stupid here, but OOTB config for Jetty only logs Jetty logs at INFO and I set my own classes to log at DEBUG etc. Configuring Jetty so that all classes log at DEBUG shows the Jersey log. Mea culpa.

Comment: Michal, is there some way to switch off the Jersey ApplicationHandler log on startup?

Comment: Not really. If you consider this to be a security issue, please file a improvement in our JIRA (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY) and we'll come up with a property that would turn it off.

Comment: Not so much a security issue as a UX issue. Created https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2365

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful, but I'm running Jersey 2 in tomcat 7 as a windows service. I enabled the logging filter in web.xml and *unfortunately* they come out as INFO entries in the stderr log that the windows wrapper creates, not stdout, like you'd expect. Since this is consistent with above comments, it must be a feature, not a bug.

Comment: "For 2.x we're working on a development mode which would include tracing support"  any news here?   I'm a Jersey newbie and I think I really need such a simple tracer or a some very verbose logging.

Comment: Not getting any logs when configured in web.xml. it works when i register it using ResourceConfig subclass

Comment: LoggingFilter is now deprecated, we should use LoggingFeature instead. But how to do it in web.xml with LoggingFeature?

Comment: Links are dead.