# How to run a Custom ServletRequestListener before every API Call in Drop Wizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am new to drop Wizard java framework and trying to write a custom ServletRequestListener which will act as a filter before and after execution of a API Web Request.

I have created following class.

```
@WebListener
public class CustomRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRequestListener.class);

@Override
public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) {
    logger.info("Iam here");
        // do something
}

@Override
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) {
      //..do something once the thread execution is over
}
```

I want above filter to execute before a Rest API call is made.
Its not working for me, Is there any other way t do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the REST API you are using, it might not use servlets, so you might not see any calls to a ServletReqestListener.
See [How do I get Jersey 2.2 (JAX-RS) to generate log output, including Json request bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268827/how-do-i-get-jersey-2-2-jax-rs-to-generate-log-output-including-json-request) for how to add a logging request filter, or see here https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html#logging for the official jersey docs on logging.